# Error "IllegalStateException: No target Validator set" after upgrade from Spring Boot 3.1.5 to 3.2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, web-services, upgrade

After upgrading a reactive application from Spring Boot 3.1.5 to Spring Boot 3.2.0, I get the following error:

```plaintext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No target Validator set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.forExecutables(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:396)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationAdapter.invokeValidatorForArguments(MethodValidationAdapter.java:257)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationAdapter.validateArguments(MethodValidationAdapter.java:240)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.HandlerMethodValidator.validateArguments(HandlerMethodValidator.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.HandlerMethodValidator.applyArgumentValidation(HandlerMethodValidator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:164)
    ...
```

There is no other change in the code, the exception did not occur before in Spring Boot 3.1.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is caused by a change of logic in the dependency on `spring-boot-starter-validation`. In my Spring Boot 3.1.5 applications, I either had not this dependency at all, or had it with the `test` scope. Now in spring Boot 3.2.0 it is apparently mandatory. The `pom.xml` file must contain

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Without this, any controller method with parameters annotated with some `jakarta.validation.*` annotations, such as `jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull`, throws the described exception. The exception is thrown by Spring and the method is not even called at all.